# window.find not working in iframe on webpage

Tags: javascript, iframe

I wrote a JavaScript code to find text on window using `window.find`. It works fine for the web pages but does not work inside IFRAME text ( i have to search the text on web page and IFRAME  also). The purpose is to highlight searched text in blue background just like browsers search does.

Can anybody put me in the right direction what mistake I am making
Below is my code

```
function searchText(str)
{
     window.find(str)
}
```

Comment: _"Non-standard: This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future."_

Comment: thanks @Andreas for comment. Actually above functionality i am implementing for  in house people of own company. not visible to outside world

Comment: Have you tried `[iframe element reference].contentWindow.find(str)`?

Comment: Hi @CBroe ur answer really worked for me , tons of thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can only access the contents of an iframe with JS if the content is from the same domain.

If it is -> `$("#iFrame").contents().find()`

Comment: yeah i tried above code earlier but no luck. But the major task is to highlight the text as window.find() does

Comment: Is the iframe loaded from the same domain?

Comment: yes @Daniel, it from same domain